# How can I pass function as an argument in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I would like to create a sticky element that disappears when a certain `div` (bottles) get to bottom of the screen.

I have this code that works:

```js
function update() {
   const bottles = document.getElementById("bottles");
   const rect = bottles.getBoundingClientRect();
   const distance = window.innerHeight - rect.bottom; //value is 0 when bottom of bottles is at the bottom of screen
        
   if (distance < 0) {
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("sticky-element")).forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("hidden"));
   } else {
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("sticky-element")).forEach((el) => el.classList.add("hidden"));
   }
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', update);
update();
```

However this is not the best code and it's going to be part of AB testing so the distances would have to be different. Therefore I tried to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```js
function update(distance) {
     if (distance < 0) {
          Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("sticky-element")).forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("hidden"));
     } else {
          Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("sticky-element")).forEach((el) => el.classList.add("hidden"));
     }
}
```

In case of the option A:

```
function elementDistance() {
   const bottles = document.getElementById("bottles");
   const rect = bottles.getBoundingClientRect();
   const distance = window.innerHeight - rect.bottom; //value is 0 when bottom of bottles is at the bottom of screen
   return distance;
}
    
document.addEventListener('scroll', update);
document.addEventListener('scroll', elementDistance);
    
update(elementDistance);
```

In case of the option B:

```js
function elementDistance() {
   const distance = some other values
   return distance;
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', update);
document.addEventListener('scroll', elementDistance);
update(elementDistance);
```

Comment: `update(elementDistance);` -> `update(elementDistance());` will pass the value. If you actually need do execute the function inside `update` then `if (distance < 0)` -> `if (distance() < 0)`

Comment: In the case of either variant you'll want to fix the scroll listener  `document.addEventListener('scroll', () => { update(elementDistance()); });`

Comment: omg the distance() worked! the mystery is solved! for whatever reason update(elementDistance()); didn't work.

Comment: Thanks James, the scroll listener fixed the first VLAZ solution :) Thanks guys, muuch appreciated

Comment: Why not `const distance = elementDistance();`